# Cannot do simple Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have multiple recursions in Prolog but when i do similar recursion to pow in result block it says:

> is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated.

```
pow(_,0,1):-!.
pow(X,N,XN):-
    N>0,
    N1 is N - 1,
    pow(X, N1, XN1),
    XN is XN1 * X.

result(_,0,_):-!.    
result(X, N, Res):-
    N2 is N - 1,
    N1 is 2*N - 1,
    pow(X, N1, Numer),
    pow(-1, N2, One),
    writeln('before'),
    result(X, N2, RS1),
    writeln('after'),
    writeln('RS1: ' + RS1),
    Res is RS1+One*(Numer/N1).
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably for the reason that because

```
result(_,0,_):-!.
```

is true for *any* 3rd (and 1st) argument where 2nd one is 0, so in

```
result(X, N2, RS1)
```

the `RS1` variable cannot be computed when `N2` is 0. (It's just like to ask a question to find **x** when **0 * x = 0** is given, for example.)

If you fix the value for `RS1` when `N2=0`, e.g. using a conditional like this

```
(N2 =:= 0 -> RS1 is 1; result(X, N2, RS1)),
```

it will work.

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern in Prolog is the use of *helper* predicates with an *accumulator*.

X<sup>*n*</sup> is repeated multiplication. It's shorthand for 1 * X * X ..., repeated *n* times, correct? And that gives you the prolog predicate you need.

Try something like this:

```
% ---------------------------------------------------------
% pow/3 — Our public predicate to raise X to the Nth power,
% unifying the result with R 
% ---------------------------------------------------------
pow( X , N , R ) :-
  pow(X,N,1,R)
  .

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% pow/4 — Our private helper predicate
%
% It also raised X to the Nth power, but uses an accumulator, T,
% in which to accumulate the result.
% --------------------------------------------------------------
pow( _ , 0 , R , R ) .  % Once we hit the 0th power, we're done: just unify the accumulator with R.
pow( X , N , T , R ) :- % To evaluate X to the Nth power...
  N > 0,                % 0. For non-negative, integral values of N.
  T1 is T * X,          % 1. Multiple the accumulator by X
  N1 is N-1,            % 2. Decrement the power N by 1
  pow(X,N1,T1,R)        % 3. Recursively evaluate X to the N-1th power
  .                     % Easy!
```